# How to get am instance name of a dynamicaly created movieClip or name?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, actionscript, flash-cs3

**For AS 3**

I have a class which crate a panel with close button. and i create an instance of this class
like this

```
function _smallThumbClick(evt:MouseEvent):void {
   var _popup:Popup=new Popup( square.width ,evt.currentTarget.y, evt.currentTarget);
   addChild(_popup);
  }
```

and this mouse event from the thumbnail(suppose), so if i click on the thumb it will create popup. so i want to close all other or previously opened pop window.

How do u get the popup class object to close from another class..

or is there any alternate method for detect instance of the movieclip or class..

Answer (score 2):

You can store a reference to the popup in a public variable and access it from outside.

```
public var popup:Popup;
function _smallThumbClick(evt:MouseEvent):void
{
    popup = new Popup( square.width ,evt.currentTarget.y, evt.currentTarget);
    addChild(popup);
}
```

Now you can call `this.removeChild(popup);` from this class or `obj.removeChild(obj.popup);` from another class.

If you are on flex, you can use [PopUpManager](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/langref/mx/managers/PopUpManager.html) class.